# Bring Control into ViewPort on Focus Change for ScrollViewer SL4

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, scrollview

Basically I'm looking for something exactly like [BringIntoViewOnFocusChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.bringintoviewonfocuschange) for SL4, I need whichever control has focus to automatically move into view of the `ViewPort` of a `ScrollViewer` whether it be Vertical or Horizontal scrolling enabled or both. So if say there's large view, with controls out of view, as a user tabs along it places whatever control that takes focus into view for smooth scrolling without having to do it manually.

I've done this with behaviors and setting `VerticalOffset` and attaching it to each individual object, but there has to be a better way and this has to have come up for folks often (except I couldnt find anything specific searching) so I'd really rather not re-invent the wheel here if I can. So please, share some enlightenment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going this route that happened to be what I was looking for and works splendid. Thanks to all who looked.

http://mattduffield.wordpress.com/2011/01/15/automatically-scrolling-to-a-selected-item-in-a-scrollviewer-in-silverlight/

Answer (score 0):

You may find this of interest: [Silverlight BringIntoView() extension method (with OnGotFocus behavior)](http://weblogs.asp.net/dotjosh/archive/2009/11/05/bringintoview-extension-method-for-silverlight-with-behavior.aspx)

Comment: This does basically what I already have with VerticalOffset, I'll need to figure out how to work in Horizontal consideration as well. Basically I was trying to avoid spending to much time on this one to focus on other things hence the bounty, but this just puts me back where I started. Thank you though.